# How use ecma5 in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm using webpack to join my javascript files and uglify.
But, I bought a premium theme in website, the frontend isn't mine.
I need to join 10 different javascript files, but when the file is joined, crash the application, because the script use the `export default var` instead of only join files.

There is a way to only join files?
Thanks for this.

Comment: are you asking about `importing files` into your main bundle?
i.e. (not use `export/import`, then you'd need to use to import `var file = require('path/to/file)`;  and to export `exports = module.exports = variableName`)

Comment: I dont want export/import files. I want only join files. In rails, for example, I make:
// require jquery
// require jquery.owl-carousel
And create only one file joined.

Comment: so you want to bundle everything as one file - say like browserify/webpack?

i.e. the client will be served one file